# Entity Framework with dynamic schema selection

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have different schema for each user in a SQL Server database. With Entity Framework, I have to add record in to the user specific schema tables.

Right now my db is like below.
Here S1, S2, S3 are the schemas.

```
S1.T1, S2.T1 and S3.T1
```

and so on

```
DbSchemaEntities db = new DbSchemaEntities();

db.T1.Add(new T1() {Name="S1Data"});
db.T1.Add(new T1() {Name="S2Data"});

db.T1.Add(new T1() {Name="SxData"});

db.SaveChanges();
```

The above code only inserting the data in to the schema S1 only.

In my `.edmx` file, the xml contains the following:

```
 <EntityContainer Name="DbSchemaModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="T1" EntityType="Self.T1" Schema="S1" store:Type="Tables" />
 </EntityContainer>
```

How can I dynamically choose the schema at run time?

Comment: What are S1, S2 and S3 ? Are those databases ? Please Shed some more info

Comment: Here S1, S2 and S3 are the Schemas in one Databse. In Each schema has the same tables. Based on the user role the schema choose dynamically in entity framework.